# How to use json object in ngx-Swiper-wrapper

Tags: angular, swiper.js

in ngx-Swiper-wrapper i am directly binding my response code. Sample code is given below.
this is my

```
 getResponse(){
            this.responseService.getListofResponse().subscribe(resp =>{
             this.responseList = resp;
            });}
```

componet.html

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper" *ngFor="let resp of responseList">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">{{resp.name}}</div>
       </div>
    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
<!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

instead of Json object if i use any array it's working please let me know how to use subscribed response form the same as above.